# Cut Bathroom Supply Tube

Tags: bathroom, floor

I cut my hot water supply tube while replacing a damaged piece of flooring in my bathroom  - pretty much cut it in half and now can't get it to stop leaking. How can I fix it to prevent future leaks?

Comment: How much of the pipe do you have access to? That is, if you complete the cut completely through the pipe, how much pipe will remain sticking out of the wall or floor or whatever?

Comment: Can you give more details and/or a picture?  Is the supply line under the floor, in the wall, or out in the open?  What's it made of?

Comment: What kind of pipe would be really useful? CPVC, copper, galvenized, pex?